# Distribute messages to a large number of subscribers at once - AWS Websocket API

Tags: aws-lambda, websocket, aws-api-gateway

I am using AWS Websocket API. In the worst case scenario I have more than 500 live connections. I need to deliver some messages to all these subscribers. The maximum latency between the first and the last receiver for messages need to be kept at 500ms or less. Any architectural suggestions that I can consider?

Comment: Can you provide more context on what type of messages and the business objective you were trying to solve?

Comment: Well these are regular message updates that I need to send to whoever connected. The payload sizes that needs to be sent is relatively small.